# Visual studio slow to start website

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have been searching for why visual studio is slow to start up a website when debugging.

It takes around 3-40 sec incl build of two projects.

Is that slow, or is it normal?

And if its not normal is there anything to do?

Thanks

Comment: I personally find VS2013 slow all around, you need some pretty good hardware to run it flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Project Properties => Build => Before running startup page: Change Build Web Site to Build Page
```